# Iframe automatic height 100% with cross domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, height

I have tried a lot of solutions but in my site no works.

Now i use:

```
<iframe src="http://www.travelstoremaker.com/ibe/turismoin/porch?command=flights" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="906" height="5000"></iframe>
```

You can see it here: http://turismo-in.it/voli-in-italia/

Now i have found this:

```
    var transport = new easyXDM.transport.BestAvailableTransport({
    local: "../hash.html",
    remote: "http://provider.easyxdm.net/example/resized_iframe.html",
    container: document.getElementById("element_that_should_contain_the_frame"),
    onMessage: function(message, origin){
        this.container.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].style.height = message + "px";
    }
});
```

*And then you put the following in the iframes body after the content*

```
    var transport = new easyXDM.transport.BestAvailableTransport({}, function(){
    transport.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight);
});
```

But how to do it? Where i must add it? It works?! There is a solution for resize automatically height of an iframe in cross domain?

P.S. I can't change code in my page iframed but only in my site

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the code on the iframed page, then you can't get the required height. I've tried many solutions and the only one I've had work is using post message. However you must be able to post the message FROM the iframe.